# If equals statement against a dictionary?

Tags: python

Evening Guys,

New to Python and wondering if someone can take a quick look at the beginning of a POS system I am working on.

I want the employee to have to enter their ID number to operate the system. So I placed the employee name and number in a dictionary. And tried to do an If/Else function to match the input against the Employee IDs. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
employee_IDs = {'Sam': 407427,
                'Bart': 101026,
                'Mike': 445002,
                }
employee_number = input('Employee ID: ')

if employee_number != employee_IDs:
    print("Invalid employee ID")
else:

    name = input('Enter Your Name: ')
    address = input('Enter Your Address: ')
    phone_number = input('Enter Your Phone Number: ')
    print('Hello', name,'!!! What would you like to order?')
    print("{:" "^80}".format(""))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your dictionary seems backwards - swapping the keys and values would be more useful

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple fundamental problems in your code that you should address.

The first thing to realize here is that the `input()` function will always return a string. With that in mind, if you actually compare string to an integer (you have an integer in your dictionary), you will never pass an equality check.

The second item to note, is that you never *actually* properly look to see if the data you want to validate is *in* your dictionary.

When you do this:

```
employee_number != employee_IDs
```

You are not performing a proper containment check to see if your data is inside the dictionary.

If all you want to do is validate that the employee_id is *not* valid, then you need to check the *values* of the dictionary. This can be done by calling the `values` method against the dictionary, and then using the *containment* check `in`:

```
if employee_id not in employee_IDs.values()
```

However, this won't work! Because `employee_id` is a *string* and your values are all integers, so you need to call `int` on the `employee_id` to actually compare the proper types with one another:

```
if int(employee_id) not in employee_IDs.values()
```

I suggest you read the [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) documentation, and take the time to go through some of the relevant parts of the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), which will greatly help your learning and solving some of these problems in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I really should have slept on this. Because I realized it this morning.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string to a dict, which will always fail. If you want to test if the input matches one of the numbers associated with the names in the dict, the test should be something like `if int(employee_number) in employee_IDs.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if employee_number != employee_IDs:
```

you want to have

```
if int(employee_number) not in employee_IDs.values():
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
employee_IDs = {'Sam': 407427,
                'Bart': 101026,
                'Mike': 445002,
                }
employee_number = input('Employee ID: ')

try:
    if int(employee_number) not in employee_IDs.values():
        print("Invalid employee ID")
    else:
        name = input('Enter Your Name: ')
        address = input('Enter Your Address: ')
        phone_number = input('Enter Your Phone Number: ')
        print('Hello', name,'!!! What would you like to order?')
        print("{:" "^80}".format(""))
finally:
    print("Invalid employee ID")
```

the sample log like this：

```
Employee ID: 407427
Enter Your Name: 21
Enter Your Address: 13212
Enter Your Phone Number: 54564
Hello 21 !!! What would you like to order?


Process finished with exit code 0
```